# Refactoring ArrayList write to file

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm not sure how to efficiently re-factor the below code.

In the code below, there are 2 methods which each write data to a file. They are both quite similar except for:

- First method accepts a single object parameter and then calls an external method for the write
- Second method accepts an ArrayList of the objects as a paramter and loops over the ArrayList to perform the writes, directly invoking the writer.

Common sense tells me that this can be re-factored into a single write method which these two methods would then call, but not sure how to achieve this.

```java
    public void updateAccount(Account account) {
        String outputString = outputStringCreator(account);
        writeOutputString(outputString);
        }

    public void updateAccounts(ArrayList<Account> accounts) {
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
            for(Account account : accounts) {
                writer.write(outputStringCreator(account));
                writer.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO issue: " + e.getMessage());
        } 

        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't close writer: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeOutputString(String outputString) {
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
            writer.write(outputString);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO issue: " + e.getMessage());
        } 

        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't close writer: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily simplify overloading methods where one takes single parameter and other takes collection like this:

```
void foo( ObjectType object ) {
    //pack object into singleton list 
    foo( List.of( object ) ); 
}
void foo( List< ObjectType > objects ) { 
    //execute logic on collection
}
```

Your method that takes collection should be able to handle cases where list has one element. That way you can easily just pass singleton list from overloading method and write only single algorithm.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even considered that approach. I've managed to refactor this now, many thanks!